# Bootstraps modal on close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm retrieving datas on success with jquery ajax and I output theme in bootstraps modal. What I'm trying to do is to bind an event on modal close, but doesn't seems to work.

```
   $(document).on('click', 'a#edit-button', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();    
           var id = $(e.target).data('id');
           var url = 'edit.php?id=' + $(e.target).data('id');
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               success: function(data)
               {
                   $('<div class="modal" id="myModal">' + data + '</div>').modal(); // show response from the php script.
               },
                error:function(){

                   alert('Error!');

                }
             }
```

);
         });

```
   $('#myModal.modal').bind('hidden', function () {
      alert('TEST');
      //$('#example.table').dataTable().fnDraw();
     });
```

Comment: Maybe try $('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
      alert('TEST');
      //$('#example.table').dataTable().fnDraw();
     });

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!! tried but won't work

Comment: Ah, modal is dynamically generated, so try to not generate it dynamically, or use `live` instead of `on`

Comment: @PeterM  `live()` is deprecated and `on()` is preferred method . See API docs

Comment: thanks for your advice I'm going to give a try!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modelID')
    .on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('hide');
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('hidden');
    })
    .on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('show');
    })
    .on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('shown');
    });
```